# Given a certain differentiable inequality of f show that $a\geq\pi$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

We are given a positive number a and a function $f:[0,a]\rightarrow[0,+\infty)$ that satisfies $f(0)=f(a)=0$ and $\forall_{x\in(0,a)}f(x)+f''(x)>0$. Prove that $a\ge\pi$.

Obviously we can assume that $a$ is the first point after $0$ for which $f(x)=0$.
It is so because if $x\in(0,a)$ and $f(x)=0$ then f satisfies all of this problems conditions on the interval $[0,x]$ so we have to show that that $x\ge\pi$ anyway (the first such $x$ must exist since $f$ can't be constantly $0$ on any interval $[0,\epsilon)$ because then $\exists_{x\in[0,\epsilon)}f(x)=0$ and $f''(x)=0$ so $\exists_{x\in(0,a)}f(x)+f''(x)=0$. Contradiction. And it can't be that $f$ hits $0$ infinitely often near $0$ since then $f''$ would be unbounded from the negative side so we would find $x\in(0,a)$ such that $f(x)+f''(x)<0$. Another contradiction.

Having said that I am lost. The condition $\forall_{x\in(0,a)}f(x)+f''(x)>0$ invokes some use of trig functions (both $\sin$ and $\cos$ satisfy $f(x)+f''(x)=0$) and I have experimented with a number of functions. Here are some of my findings (here we assume $a<\pi$):

$\forall_{n\in\Bbb{N}}\space g(x)=f(x)\pm n\sin(x)$ satisfies $g(x)+g''(x)>0$

$\forall_{n\in\Bbb{N}}\space g(x)=f(x)\pm n\cos(x)$ satisfies $g(x)+g''(x)>0$

$g=\dfrac{f}{\sin}$ has a positive second derivative in $x$ if and only if $f'(x)+\dfrac{f(x)}{\tan(x)}>0$

I get that the condition $\forall_{x\in(0,a)}f(x)+f''(x)>0$ somehow dictates how fast can $f$ get back to $0$ from $0$ but my intuiton is out on this one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mentioned $c$ in the title. Is it a typo?

Comment: Oh yes, Ill change it in a moment